# shorten something in AS 2.0 using eval or set?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

```
eval("_parent.volumetone" + target1)._yscale = Math.round(number)/1.5+50;
eval("_parent.volumetone" + target2)._yscale = Math.round(number)/1.5+50;
eval("_parent.volumetone" + target3)._yscale = Math.round(number)/1.5+50;
eval("_parent.volumetone" + target4)._yscale = Math.round(number)/1.5+50;
eval("_parent.volumetone" + target5)._yscale = Math.round(number)/1.5+50;
eval("_parent.volumetone" + target6)._yscale = Math.round(number)/1.5+50;
eval("_parent.volumetone" + target7)._yscale = Math.round(number)/1.5+50;
eval("_parent.volumetone" + target8)._yscale = Math.round(number)/1.5+50;
eval("_parent.volumetone" + target9)._yscale = Math.round(number)/1.5+50;
eval("_parent.volumetone" + target10)._yscale = Math.round(number)/1.5+50;
eval("_parent.volumetone" + target11)._yscale = Math.round(number)/1.5+50;
eval("_parent.volumetone" + target12)._yscale = Math.round(number)/1.5+50;
eval("_parent.volumetone" + target13)._yscale = Math.round(number)/1.5+50;
eval("_parent.volumetone" + target14)._yscale = Math.round(number)/1.5+50;
eval("_parent.volumetone" + target15)._yscale = Math.round(number)/1.5+50;
```

i have these lines of repetitive code. the variables target1 to target15 are a random number between 1 and 110. so one may point to _parent.volumetone49 and adjust its _yscale for example.
the code above works the way i want, but i want it shorter.

here's something i tried with no success:

```
for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
set("_parent.volumetone" + ("target"+i) + "._xscale", Math.round(funhousenumber)/1.5+50);
}
```

basically having a loop that starts at 1 and goes to 15, then replaces target1 with target+i, i being 1, which would give target1 and thus the number contained in it.

maybe i have to use eval()? i'm still not sure what i'm doing but i'm learning as i go.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    _parent["volumetone" + this["target" + i]]._yscale = Math.round(funhousenumber) / 1.5 + 50);
}
```

The bracket syntax is a way to access properties of an object by using a qualified name. It will set or get the value of the property with the given name, just like the dot syntax, but the difference is that the dot syntax is compile time and the bracket syntax is runtime. The first is generally more useful when writing type safe code, whereas the latter is more useful when writing dynamic code such as this. Consider the following code, which is functionally equivalent:

```
foo.bar = 1;
foo["bar"] = 1; // Functionally equivalent to the line above
```

In your case, in order to reduce repetitive code and still get the values from the target* variables, you would use the bracket syntax inside of the loop. That's what the following does in the snippet above:

```
this["target" + i]
```

You should replace 'this' with whatever object the properties belong to, unless they actually belong to 'this'.

Comment: They are pretty useful for a lot of purposes. Dynamic objects in flash behave much like hash tables, in that the properties can have pretty much any valid string as key. So while you can't have a property called "!123€" in dot notation, it's valid in bracket notation. Ie, this won't even compile: myObject.!123$ = 1; Whereas this will compile and run just fine (provided myObject is a dynamic object): myObject["!123$"] = 1;

Answer (score 0):

You can use bracket syntax:

```
for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {   
 _parent["volumetone" + i]._xscale = Math.round(funhousenumber)/1.5+50);
}
```

Any property of an object can be referenced using dot notation or bracket notation, so instead of object.name you can use object["name"].

I regard eval() and set() as more or less deprecated, and would not recommend using them.